# Пропадают счетчики с сайта

Tags: веб-программирование, счетчики

Доброго времени суток! Заметил такую особенность на некоторых сайтах, в том числе и на моих, которые я сам делал. Там начинают пропадать картинки-счетчики. Посмотреть можете сами:[image]

И еще вот мой сайт:

[image]

С чем это может быть связано? И как с этим бороться? Проверял в разных браузерах и на разных компьютерах, везде та же проблема.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Бороться с этим можно так:

```
<img src="liveinternetcounter.png" onerror="this.src='staticounter.png';" >
```

То есть предварительно сделайте картинку staticounter.png, ее например можно по крону раз в час подгружать на свой сервер и отдавать уже со своего сервера. Отдача будет происходить, если произошла ошибка при загрузке счетчика.

Answer (score 1):

Любой человек, имеющий малые знания в веб, или программировании может легко сам анализировать данные проблемы, и поэтому из выше сказанного могу предположить следующее:

1. Недоступен узел, где расположена картинка. (Проблема может быть как со стороны сервера, так и с вашей стороны, провайдера).
2. У вас блокирует Adblocker, или другие блокирующие рекламу программы.

Comment: Ну сомневаюсь, что счетчики майла или других популярных сайтов будут иметь проблемы на стороне сервера. Это не только на моих сайтах, я сказал, что также находил в интернете сайты, где также теряются картинки от счетчиков. Программ-блокировщиков не стоит.

Answer (score 1):

Это связано с тем что сервера где расположен сервис счетчика перегружен или же просто не отдает ответ.

Как правило это от Вас не завесит, все нужно делать на стороне сервиса который предоставляет Вам услугу счетчика на сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Я такое наблюдаю, когда кто-либо через мой Wi-Fi торренты грузит.Может скорость интернета маленькая и происходит превышение лимита ожидания